# How can I use regex expressions to split a string between numbers, specified strings, and individual characters if they don't form a specified word?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I am trying to find a way to split a String into certain sections using a regex. My desired result would be like this:

```
input: "3.0catsdogs}qd7cats8.0dogs"
//specified strings: "cats", "dogs"

output[]: ["3.0","cats","dogs","}","q","d","7","cats","8.0","dogs"]
```

Each element of the array should either match one of the specified words or be a number (can be a double or not), or if neither of those conditions are true, then separate by each character.

I understand that I can use if conditions and for loops which would not be very difficult to implement, but it would be very annoying. I can't find any way to put this into a regex. There are multiple conditions here that I want to put into place but I am unclear as to how to combine them, especially the splitting into each individual character if the other two statements(number or one of the specified strings) aren't true. I want to replace all of this code simply into a couple lines without writing an excess of unnecessary conditions and loops.

I have an idea that I could split the numbers and non-numbers apart, and then use for loops to check if each of the non-numbers are contain one of the specified strings using if conditions, using a while loop until there is no more splitting necessary. But.. that is highly unideal.
for example:

```
input: "3.0catsdogs}qd7cats8.0dogs"
//specified strings: "cats", "dogs"

regex output: ["3.0","catsdogs}qd","7","cats","8.0","dogs"]

//input of iteration 1 is the above regex output
while loop iteration 1: ["3.0","cats","dogs}qd","7","cats","8.0","dogs"]
while loop iteration 2: ["3.0","cats","dogs","}qd","7","cats","8.0","dogs"]
while loop iteration 3: ["3.0","cats","dogs","}","qd","7","cats","8.0","dogs"]
while loop iteration 4: ["3.0","cats","dogs","}","q","d","7","cats","8.0","dogs"]
while loop iteration 5: finds no more changes needed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of splitting, it's easier to find all matches using an alternation pattern instead:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String input = "3.0catsdogs}qd7cats8.0dogs";
        final String regex = "cats|dogs|\\d(?:\\.\\d*)?|.";
        final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
        final ArrayList matches = new ArrayList();
        while (m.find()) {
            matches.add(m.group());
        }
        System.out.println(matches.toString());
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
[3.0, cats, dogs, }, q, d, 7, cats, 8.0, dogs]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/HeftyFlamboyantForm

Comment: Nice approach, +1. Note that `m.group(0)` is equivalent to just `m.group()` though.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like the following. It uses `re.split` to do the heavy lifting based on matching a regex with a set of words or a number:

```python
import re

words = ["cats", "dogs"] # pretend no meta-chars here
_int = r"0|[1-9]\d*"
num = rf"(?:{_int}\.{_int}|{_int})"    # accept 1 or 1.0 or 0.9 but not .9 or 1.
regex = rf"({num}|(?:{'|'.join(words)}))" 

sample = "3.0catsdogs}qd7cats8.0dogs"
list(filter(bool, re.split(regex, sample)))
# ['3.0', 'cats', 'dogs', '}qd', '7', 'cats', '8.0', 'dogs']
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired output, and is not written in Java.